# What are the advantages of storing your schema as arrays or hash fields?

Tags: nosql, database-schema, rethinkdb, document-based-database

This applies to rethink DB. Is it better to have a schema with embedded arrays or hash fields as arrays? Keeping my intentions simple.. I am trying to keep track of daily statistics. But I am in between deciding what schema structure is better. Let me elaborate..

Pure array schema:

```
schema = [
  {
    title: 'foobar',
    dates: [
      {
        date: 20130926,
        views_count: 10,
        click_count: 10
      },
      {
        date: 20130927,
        views_count: 20,
        click_count: 20
      },
      {
        date: 20130928,
        views_count: 30,
        click_count: 30
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Hash field array schema:

```
schema = [
  {
    title: 'foobar',
    dates: [
      '20130926' => {
        views_count: 10,
        click_count: 10
      },
      '20130927' => {
        views_count: 20,
        click_count: 20
      },
      '20130928' => {
        views_count: 30,
        click_count: 30
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

One that I can think of is.. It's easier to prevent duplicity of dates with the latter. Any other advantages? Or, is there a common convention that developers prefer?

Comment: If you picked a single DB and asked this question, it might be answerable. But, by tagging many, it's hard to say what the advantages are, as each platform is different, and may handle your schemas in a variety of ways. The answer for MongoDB is absolutely different than the answer for CouchDB for example. I've marked to close as "too broad."

Comment: @WiredPrairie I've removed mongo DB. This question applies only to rethink DB. Please reopen the question. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for making the changes.

Comment: Neither method is inherently better than the other. They're pretty similar performance wise, at least when there's a small number of elements. The question really comes down to what sorts of operations you're planning to do. Is accessing elements by date to increment the `click_count` field going to be a common operation? If so I think you might be better off using hash fields.

Comment: @JoeDoliner Yes, the intention here is to choose 2 or more dates and group their click_count values together to get the total. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 2):

IMHO, your application trumps any DBMS.  Instead of focusing on your DB storage choices, focus on your application needs, programming and performance.  Persist your program data, then iteratively benchmark and optimize for the dominant cases with schema changes only when necessary.  Your application will answer your storage questions.  For example, in general:

(1) if you need predominantly ordered access to dates, then use array
(2) if you need fast random access to many dates, then use hash

Both the programming language and DBMS semantics matter. Even if the DB has ordered hashes, you language could loose this, e.g., Hashes in Ruby 1.9 and newer are ordered, but were unordered previously.

Of course your schema choices are VERY important.  But IMHO, a primary strength of document (non-columnar object data NoSQL) DBMSs is the ability to match natural data structures in programming languages.  So I gently encourage you to go back to your application/program as the focus for both questions and answers.